# make can't read file written by itself

Tags: makefile

Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
.PONY: stamp diff
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

diff:
    diff <(./stamp.txt) <(docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up)

stamp:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up > stamp.txt

all: stamp diff
```

Output:

```
$ make
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up > stamp.txt
Starting ci-test ... done
diff <(./stamp.txt) <(docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up)
/bin/bash: ./stamp.txt: Permission denied
Starting ci-test ... done
0a1,4
> Attaching to ci-test
> ci-test    | Python 3.7.3
> ci-test exited with code 0
> 
\ No newline at end of file
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'diff' failed
make: *** [diff] Error 1

$ ll
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  4 mirror mirror 4096 May 26 07:38 ./
drwxrwxr-x 47 mirror mirror 4096 May 24 15:58 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 mirror mirror  210 May 26 07:34 docker-compose.test.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 mirror mirror  103 May 26 07:33 .env
drwxrwxr-x  9 mirror mirror 4096 May 26 07:36 .git/
drwxrwxr-x  3 mirror mirror 4096 May 24 03:29 .idea/
-rw-rw-r--  1 mirror mirror  664 May 26 07:38 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 mirror mirror   92 May 26 07:36 stamp.txt
```

Questions. Why I got `/bin/bash: ./stamp.txt: Permission denied` and how to fix it?

Comment: `<(./stamp.txt)` - do you want to *run* `stamp.txt` and use its output? I think you want only `< ./stamp.txt` so use its content. In your case the permission denied means `./stamp.txt` doesn't have execution right.

Comment: @uzsolt I want to save output of `docker-compose` execution to file `stamp.txt` and after that compare this file with output of `docker-compose` execution again. After changes: `diff <(./stamp.txt) <(docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up)` to `diff <./stamp.txt <(docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up)` i got `diff: missing operand after '/dev/fd/63'` error

Comment: Then @uzsolt's suggestion *solved the problem you asked about*. Note also that if you want to update both the `stamp` target and the `diff` target when you run `make` without specifying any targets, then the `all` rule should be the first in your makefile.

Comment: Note: `.PONY` should be spelt `.PHONY` - it probably does not affect you (more by luck), but if a file called `stamp` or `diff` get created then your rules won't run without this spelt correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your makefile. Here is a simplified version

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
.PHONY: stamp diff
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

diff:
        @diff <(./stamp.txt) <(echo "aaa")

stamp:
        @echo > stamp.txt

all: stamp diff
```

This line: `@diff <(./stamp.txt) <(echo "aaa")` will pass result of execution of `./stamp.txt`. I guess, what you are looking for is

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
.PHONY: stamp diff
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

diff:
        @diff <(cat ./stamp.txt) <(echo "aaa")

stamp:
        @echo > stamp.txt

all: stamp diff
```